# WCF: Is it good practice to send null response from Server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service where I am processing Customer object and based on that I need to send array of Products related to customer.

So I question is, if there is **no products** for particular Customer 
should I return the Null value or empty array of Products to the WCF Client?

Please advise the best approach to do this.

```
 [OperationContract]   
 Product[] DoProcess(Customer customer);

 if(Product not found by Customer)
 {
      // return null;
      // or
      // return new Product[];
 }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's better to `return new Product[]` so at the client side you don't need to check the condition of null.

Comment: absolutely rule of thumb, whether or not its a service a collection should return empty and an object should return null. makes easy to code an expect right outcome if not interested in using a NULL pattern

Comment: This is a simple application of the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) where the null object is the empty array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct answer for that.

If you choose to return nulls on your environment as a "not found", it is ok. If your app is expecting empty arrays, go ahead.